# Wait for a value to be loaded via JSON and than load an external javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following function to set the addthis:title attribute:

```
function setTheTitle(){
        if(jQuery(".title").length > 0){
            shareTitle = jQuery(".title").text();
            jQuery("#shareButton").attr("addthis:title", shareTitle);
        } else {
            setTimeout(function(){
                setTheTitle();
            },100)
        }
    }
```

The problem is, the **shareTitle** variable is generated via a JSON object and takes a few seconds to load.

Until then, the addthis javascript loads, and see's an **empty url attr**, setting the pages default title.

```
<script src="http://www.../external_share_script.js" type="text/javascript">share script</script>
<a href="#" id="shareButton" addthis:title="" addthis:url="">the link</a>
```

**How can I delay the load of the addthis javascript until I get my value?**

Comment: Show the code that fetches the data, because that's the key to your problem.

Comment: `setTimeout(setTheTitle, 100);` is much cleaner.

Comment: In the success callback where you fetch your JSON data, you can use jQuery's `$.getScript` function to dynamically fetch the script and immediately execute it.

Comment: This script, the external js: external_share_script.js - I cannot edit, have no access to it

Comment: @user2065483: Add an ID to the script tag, and try using `$('#extern').load(function(){ setTheTitle(); });`.

Comment: @user2065483 Not following you. Is the `external_share_script.js` a third party app? Either way it shouldn't matter. Don't add the file until you successfully receive your JSON data.

Comment: I am thinking this might work Rocket Hazmat

Comment: @user2065483: It may work, it may not.  Worth a shot ^~^

Comment: Maybe I can use the getScript function, adter I get my title

Comment: using getScript can be risky on 3rd party scripts, you don't know whether or not it uses `document.write()` (which would destroy your page if you used getScript to load it). Though i guess if you tested it and it didn't destroy your page, it would be ok as long as the 3rd party doesn't later update it to use `document.write()`

Comment: I successfully loaded the script using getScript, though the share button does not work - any ideas why? I know it's a shoot in the dark question, but the clients pages need to remain private and I cannot give you a working demo

Comment: hmm...not sure right off hand. You could try rendering the button dynamically in the success callback of the `$.getScript` function. [Here](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#.UcCQZfm1E4E) is a link to the developer API page for the _AddThis_ tool. Unfortunately their sections do not use ID's so I couldn't link you directly, but check out the section titled ***Render a button at an HTML element passed by reference***. It's almost halfway down the page. This may help you. I had to do something similar with the _ShareThis_ service.